Getting ipv4 in React Native
I have a project in React Native, the server is written in node.js, url, url2, url3, etc. these are the addresses of processed requests to the server. I need the application to detect ipv4 networks when it starts, but I couldn’t do it. Everything is in typescript, but the file with the url is in javascript.
const IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.1.15";
export const url = `http://${IP_ADDRESS}:3000/register/email`;
export const url2 = `http://${IP_ADDRESS}:3000/register`;
export const url3 = `http://${IP_ADDRESS}:3000/news?category=sports`;
export const url4 = `http://${IP_ADDRESS}:3000/login`;
export const url5 = `http://${IP_ADDRESS}:3000/api/profile`;
export const url6 = `http://${IP_ADDRESS}:3000/user`;

Below is the code of the page where url3 is used
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "expo-router";
import { url3 } from "src/app/ip/config";
import { i18n } from "languages/i18n";
import { SvgUri } from "react-native-svg";

const News = () => {
  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchNews = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url3);
        setNews(response.data.articles);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Ошибка при получении новостей:", error);
      }
    };
    fetchNews();
  }, []);

  const CabinetIcon = () => {
    return (
      <SvgUri
        width="40px"
        height="40px"
        uri="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/485646/cabinet1.svg"
      />
    );
  };

  const FilterIcon = () => {
    return (
      <SvgUri
        width="40px"
        height="40px"
        uri="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/509927/filter.svg"
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
          <Link href="/profile">
            <CabinetIcon />
          </Link>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{i18n.t("pageTitle")}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
          <Link href="/filter">
            <FilterIcon />
          </Link>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <FlatList
        data={news}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View className="border-red-950 border-2 border-solid p-4 ">
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            <Text>{item.description}</Text>
            <Link href={item.url}>{i18n.t("newsLink")}</Link>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default News;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  image: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  Title: {
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    color: "purple",
    fontSize: 24,
  },
  Icona: {},
});

I've already tried to use
import { NetworkInfo } from "react-native-network-info";
 
// Get IPv4 IP (priority: WiFi first, cellular second)
NetworkInfo.getIPV4Address().then(ipv4Address => {
  console.log(ipv4Address);
});

But either I'm stupid or this method doesn't work.
